# HTML, JS Logic not working

Tags: javascript, html, math, web, logic

I am trying to create a js logic function to solve the variables in an equation like this: 2x+5x=16. The problem is that it is supposed to output x=3 y=2, but instead, it outputs x=-11 y=1. 
[image: I am using 2x+5y=16 for this result.]

```js
function solver(){
  //Get c1, c2, and the answer
  var c1=parseInt(prompt("Enter the coefficient of x:", "Example: 2 if you have 2x"));
  var c2=parseInt(prompt("Enter the coefficient of y:", "Example: 3 if you have 3y"));
  var answer=parseInt(prompt("Enter the answer:", "Example: 2x=4 it would be 4"));
  //set other variables
  var x;
  var y;
  var m;
  //setup
  x=answer/c1;
  m=answer%c1;
  //loop
  while(true){
    //if it is not an integer or it is 0
    if (isInt(m/c2) === false || m/c2 == 0){
      x=x-1;
      m=answer%x;
    }else if (isInt(m/c2)===true && m/c2 != 0){
      x=x;
      y=m/c2;
      break;
    }
  }
  alert("x="+x+" y="+y);
}
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>EXAMPLE: 2x+5y=16</h1>
<button onclick="solver()">Solve!</button>
```

Comment: if x=3 and y=2, then 2x+3y would be equal to 12.. You wont be getting 16. So, the answer is wrong..right?

Comment: Sorry, I updated it. If you check I meant to write something else.

Answer (score 0):

Because if

nx+ky=a and x=a/n,

ky=a-(na)/n=0,

but if 
x=f, y=(a-nf)/k.

You have infinitely many solutions for linear function with two unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that there are infinite amounts of solutions?

and any given X and y that sastisfy x = 8 - 2.5y will be true?, in fact you can program the algorithm fixing y = 0, and you will get x = 8.

so you can either input two sets of xy solutions or you have infinite answers.

As a thumb rule, you need as much equations as vars

PD: I dont really get what are you doing inside the loop